# Can't create QR codes with pst-barcode

Tags: pdftex, pstricks, pst-barcode

I am trying to create a QR code with latex, no example I have tried works.

barcode-test.tex

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
        \psbarcode[]{1234}{}{qrcode}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

partial output from "pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode /home/dfear/Pickle\ IT/documents/forms\ TEMP/work-order-form.tex"

```
\c@lor@to@ps ->\PSTricks 
                         _Not_Configured_For_This_Format
l.6             \psbarcode[]{1234}{}{qrcode}
                                  
! Undefined control sequence.
\XC@usec@lor ...lashchar color@#1#2\endcsname \@@ 
                                                  \fi \space 
l.6             \psbarcode[]{1234}{}{qrcode}
                                  
[1
```

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: pdftex can't process pstricks. Try with lualatex.

Comment: run it with `lualatex`  instead of `pdflatex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to use pdfLaTeX then you can use the `auto-pst-pdf` package which automatically extracts PSTricks code from the document, runs it through `latex`-`dvips`-`ps2pdf`-`pdfcrop`, and inserts the resulting graphic in the document. This requires the `-shell-escape` compilation flag.

Another issue is that the `auto-pst-pdf` toolchain does not support pdfx. The preamble is copied as it is for the creation of the PSTricks graphics, so you should make pdfx conditional in order to be used for the regular pdfLaTeX run but not for the PSTricks processing.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}
\ifpdf
\usepackage[a-1b]{pdfx}
\fi
\usepackage{pst-barcode}
\begin{document}
    \begin{pspicture}(25mm,25mm)
        \psbarcode[]{1234}{}{qrcode}
    \end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```